# my variable has 2 types

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, boolean

I need your help cause i'm in front of an uncommon issue :
In my code, I've a first function in which I proceed a request with PDO, which returns an array with result in a variable called "result".
When I do a var_dump() on this variable, it shows me :

```
array(4) { ["id_offre_var"]=> string(4) "7061" ["id_offre"]=> string(4) "3216" ["prix"]=> string(5) "29.90" ["prix_public"]=> string(5) "69.00" }
```

So, I've an array, it's ok.

Then, I call a function called **hydrate()** which in which I put my variable "result". But, in this function, when I do a var_dump() on this parameter (my previous variable "result"), it shows me that :

```
array(4) { ["id_offre_var"]=> string(4) "7061" ["id_offre"]=> string(4) "3216" ["prix"]=> string(5) "29.90" ["prix_public"]=> string(5) "69.00" } bool(false)
```

My variable is now an array AND a boolean !
Obviously, it raises me problem for next.

My first function :

```
public function getVarianteForNewsletter($idOffre)
{
    $sql = "SELECT id_offre_var, id_offre, prix, prix_public FROM apm_offres_variante
          WHERE id_offre = :offre
          ORDER BY prix
          LIMIT 0,1";
    $stmt = $this->_dal->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":offre", $idOffre, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($result);
    $Object = new OffreVariante();
    $this->hydrate($Object, $result);
    return $Object;
}
```

Then, my function hydrate():

```
protected function hydrate($Object, $params)
{
    var_dump($params);
    foreach ($params as $key=>$param)
    {
        $var = array_search($key, $this->_varsColsName);
        if ($var != false)
        {
            //if $var is a foreign key to another object
            if (array_key_exists($var, $this->_foreignKeys))
            {
                $fk = $this->_foreignKeys[$var];
                $daoName = "DAO".ucfirst($fk);
                $dao = new $daoName($this->_dal);
                $param = $dao->getById($param);
            }

            $setter = "set".ucfirst($var);
            $Object->$setter($param);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bonjour Monsieur Guillaume. It would be helpful if you share the relevant code from your 1st method and `hydrate()` method.

Comment: You're probably seeing two different `var_dump`'s

Comment: It can't be true. Probably you're running another code. Show us the whole thing.

Comment: Is your method `getVarianteForNewsletter`in a class that extends `OffreVariante`?

Comment: yes it can't be true, but no it don't runs another code. And, for testing, in my function hydrate(), I rename parameter "params" by "paramsarray", and in this way it works good. The issue is only when parameter is called "params" ;)

Comment: Amarnasan, no, my method is in another class (my model) that no extends from OffreVariante.

Comment: Then how can it call a protected method (hydrate) of another class that is not extending? You should get a Fatal Error.

Comment: after more test, issue is not about the name. In reality, issue is when the name of the parameter "params" is the same as the parameter of my foreach.
So if i have this I have the issue:
    protected function hydrate($Object, $params){
foreach ($params as $param)
}
But if i have it works:
    protected function hydrate($Object, $params){
foreach ($anotherName as $param)
}

Comment: Armanasan, because hydrate() is in class ADAO, and getVarianteForNewsletter() is in DAOOffreVariante which extends ADAO ;)

Comment: How can you run a foreach block from a non declared variable? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: it makes no sense, it is only for testing ;)

Comment: just for notice that issue come when name of the parameter is the same as the parameter in foreach ;)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, issue is caused by $key=>$item in foreach(). If I have this it don't works:

```
foreach ($params as $key=>$param)
```

But if I have just so it works :

```
foreach ($params as $param)
```

I don't know why, but I am going to try using a simple FOR loop instead.
Thanks for your help.